# Best way to install Solr across Multiple Distributions?

Tags: magento-1, magento-enterprise, solr

I have had mixed success installing Solr via aptitude as the latest stable version in the apt repo seems to be 1.7. What is the best way of installing Solr via aptitude or other means which does not require java experience?  I can't seem to find any method of installing Jetty on RHEL or CentOs via yum, either.

**Edit**

Updated to allow for multi-distribution feedback. Appreciate any advice you can lend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### On Debian/Ubuntu

The most straightforward installation is pretty easy using `tomcat` and your package manager. The dependencies will be met automatically.

```
apt-get install tomcat6
```

### On CentOS/RedHat

You need to grab some alternative repo's to make this possible

Eg.

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uhv http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

Then you can install the package from `yum`

```
yum install yum-priorities ant tomcat6 tomcat6-admin

cd /usr/src/
mkdir sun-java
cd sun-java
```

Now it gets a little trickier. Sun used to permit direct downloads; but they now have a stupid session validation in place - so download the binary via your PC and upload it to the machine.

You need both the Linux JDK and JRE.

The commands would have been:

```
wget -O jdk.rpm.bin http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u29-b11/jdk-6u29-linux-x64-rpm.bin
wget -O jre.rpm.bin http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u29-b11/jre-6u29-linux-x64-rpm.bin
```

You can alternatively use OpenJDK

```
wget http://jpackage.org/jpackage50.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jpackage50.repo
yum install -y java-1.6.0-openjdk
```

Once you've uploaded the binaries

```
chmod +x *.bin
./jre.rpm.bin
./jdk.rpm.bin
ln -s /var/lib/tomcat6 /usr/share/tomcat6
```

### Then the remaining steps

Then drop in your respective selection of `solr`

```
mkdir /usr/src/solr
cd /usr/src/solr
wget http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/ftp.apache.org/lucene/solr/3.6.1/apache-solr-3.6.1.tgz
tar xvfz apache-solr-3.6.1.tgz
cd apache-solr-3.6.1
cp dist/apache-solr-*.war /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr.war
mkdir -p /var/lib/tomcat6/solr
```

Then add the Magento `solr` configuration

```
INSTALL_DIR="/var/lib/tomcat6/solr"
touch $INSTALL_DIR/solr.xml
CORES=( "staging" "development" "live" )
for CORE in "${CORES[@]}"; do
  mkdir -p $INSTALL_DIR/$CORE/conf $INSTALL_DIR/$CORE/data 
  cp -par /usr/src/solr/apache-solr-3.6.1/example/solr/conf/* $INSTALL_DIR/$CORE/conf
  cp -par /home/path/public_html/lib/Apache/Solr/Conf/* $INSTALL_DIR/$CORE/conf
done
```

Then set up the cores

```
cat > /var/lib/tomcat6/solr/solr.xml << EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr persistent="true" sharedLib="lib">
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
    <core name="staging" instanceDir="staging" config="solrconfig.xml" schema="schema.xml" />
    <core name="development" instanceDir="development" config="solrconfig.xml" schema="schema.xml" />
    <core name="live" instanceDir="live" config="solrconfig.xml" schema="schema.xml" />
  </cores>
</solr>
EOF
```

Then finally, clean up permissions and restart `solr`

```
chown -R tomcat6:tomcat6 /var/lib/tomcat6/solr
/etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart
```

Then in Magento, you've now got 3 possible independent cores you can use for your store environments.

- `staging/solr`
- `development/solr`
- `live/solr`

*Attribution: http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/multiple-solr-cores-for-magento-on-debianubuntucentosredhat/*

Comment: I've updated my answer to suit RH/CentOS also.

Comment: This is solid gold.

Comment: ... and also why I prefer the github method. RHEL makes my life very difficult.

Comment: care to explain how you make use of the multiple solr 'cores' in Tomcat - how do you point Magento to a specific core? What about with Jetty?

Comment: Making use of them is just a case of entering the respective core name as the path in the Magento admin. Instead of `/solr` you use the path defined above, eg `/live/solr`. Tomcat is just a wrapper for a Java application, so the process should be similar with Jetty.

Comment: Accepted this answer because it's just so darned comprehensive; though I feel a bit over-engineered when it comes to using Tomcat - especially on RHEL. For those of us on Rackspace my own answer below may be the fastest method to get up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the best method of installing Solr, on both Debian distros and especially RedHat/Centos, is via the github repo `lbdremy/solr-install` - available [here](https://github.com/lbdremy/solr-install).

One caveat - this particular setup requires Jetty. If you'd like to use Solr with Tomcat, you'll have to look at some other resource, [here](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Configure-Solr-on-Ubuntu,-the-quickest-way) or [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat). The github repo does some of the hard work for you - setting up the jetty user, pulling down the most recent jdk for Solr, and unpacking everything to relevant directories. It even starts Jetty for you.

I highly recommend installation via this method. It solves all java dependencies right off the bat; plus it ensures that your dev, staging, and production environments are all running the same version. After install, you want to copy your Magento Enterprise Solr Config files from `lib/Apache/Solr/conf` to your jetty install directory. I did this with a simple:

`> cp -R lib/Apache/Solr/conf/* /usr/local/jetty/solr/conf/`

Make sure to restart Jetty after copying your configuration files:

`> sudo /etc/init.d/jetty restart`